# Publishing markers in rviz

Tags: ros

I am new to ros and I'm following the tutorials on ros wiki.
Now I am trying to visualize a marker in rviz, but it doesn't work.
I have followed the steps and created the file basic_shapes.cpp but when I run it and chance the fixed frame I don't see anything.
If I do the command "rostopic echo /visualisation_markers" it returns "WARNING: topic [/visualisation_markers] does not appear to be published yet".
Does somebody know what I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Marker" to RViz. Click on Add button in the RViz window and then add it. Then you can check that whether this topic exists by doing "rostopic list". If you see /visualization_marker in it, you're good to go!